# TableTool is not working in jquery datatable(Not showing buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jquery datatable and all my code is working fine. Then I added tooltable attribute the datatable defination with all required js,css and swf files. My code is :

```
table = $(".jqueryDataTable").dataTable( {

    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
        alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation in table.' );
        this.fnHideEmptyColumns(this);
        $('#lblReportHeader').html(reportHeader);
        $('#lblFromDate').html(fromDateHeader);
        $('#lblToDate').html(fromToHeader);
        $('#tblReportHeader').show();
    },
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "resources/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bRetrieve": true, 
    "bDestroy": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "./getReportDetails",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        newData=aoData;
        newData.push( { "name": "reportType", "value": reportType }, { "name": "reportSubType", "value": reportSubType}, { "name": "fromDate", "value": fromDate}, { "name": "toDate", "value": toDate});
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "username", "sTitle": "username"},
        { "mData": "transferType", "sTitle": "transferType"},
        { "mData": "fromAccount", "sTitle": "fromAccount"},
        { "mData": "toAccount", "sTitle": "toAccount"},
        { "mData": "amount", "sTitle": "amount"},
        { "mData": "currency", "sTitle": "currency"},
        { "mData": "transferDate", "sTitle": "transferDate"},
        { "mData": "creditDebitFlag", "sTitle": "creditDebitFlag"},
        { "mData": "fromAccountType", "sTitle": "fromAccountType"},
        { "mData": "toAccountType", "sTitle": "toAccountType"},
        { "mData": "impsChannelType", "sTitle": "impsChannelType"},
        { "mData": "impsTranType", "sTitle": "impsTranType"},
        { "mData": "IFSCCode", "sTitle": "IFSCCode"},
        { "mData": "narration", "sTitle": "narration"},
        { "mData": "customerID", "sTitle": "customerID"},
        { "mData": "customerName", "sTitle": "customerName"},
        { "mData": "fromMMID", "sTitle": "fromMMID"},
        { "mData": "fromMobileNo", "sTitle": "fromMobileNo"},
        { "mData": "toMMID", "sTitle": "toMMID"},
        { "mData": "toMobileNo", "sTitle": "toMobileNo"},
        { "mData": "paymentType", "sTitle": "paymentType"},
        { "mData": "transReferenceId", "sTitle": "transReferenceId"},
        { "mData": "transactionStatus", "sTitle": "transactionStatus"}
    ]
} );
```

But it is not showing any button for excel,pdf etc.
My resources are :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
<script src="resources/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/BootSideMenu.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/TableTools.js"></script>
```

and I have swf file at `"resources/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"` but I am not able to see any button on my UI.

What is the wrong in my code ?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please

Comment: can you put the `TableTools.js` under `datatables.min.js`, the order of including javascript files are important imo

Comment: I have corrected the import order but no effect.

Comment: @Zl3n , sorry, I can't and I am getting data from server.

Comment: You can set a variable containing the values !

Comment: use **http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf** as swfPath and be sure that flash is turned on in your browser.

Comment: I tried that too but same result.